# Build apk using buildozer with pillow: _imaging issue

Tags: android, python, kivy, python-imaging-library

Oh, hi

I wrote app with python and kivy. I built it with [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer)
But on Android it fails:

```
03-26 23:10:25.857: E/art(24531): dlopen("/data/data/pl.lolwtf.kethuporo/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/pl.lolwtf.kethuporo/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
```

Ok, so I added pillow do `buildozer.spec` requirements:

```
requirements = kivy,sqlite3,pillow
```

But on apk building (`buildozer android debug`) lots of `No such file or directory` errors appears:

```
    Downloading/unpacking pillow
  Using download cache from /home/voy/.buildozer/cache/https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FP%2FPillow%2FPillow-2.7.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow

Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow

building 'PIL._imaging' extension
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Resample.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Crop.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Geometry.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Matrix.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Quant.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/RawDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/XbmEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o
Building using 2 processes
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/outline.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/path.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/MspDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o -L/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL/_imaging.so
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/outline.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/path.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-

(...)

2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Ryb9en-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include/site/python2.7 --home=/tmp/tmpv9BKPZ:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

(...)

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

running egg_info

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL

running build_ext

building 'PIL._imaging' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Resample.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Crop.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Geometry.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Matrix.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/Quant.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/RawDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o

/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/libImaging -I/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c libImaging/XbmEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o

Building using 2 processes

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/outline.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/path.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crc32.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/LzwDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/MspDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Incremental.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o -L/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/PIL/_imaging.so

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/outline.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/path.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Access.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o: No such file or directory

(...)

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o: No such file or directory

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Ryb9en-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/include/site/python2.7 --home=/tmp/tmpv9BKPZ failed with error code 1 in /home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/venv/build/pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/voy/.pip/pip.log
[0m[1;31m# Command failed: pip install --download-cache=/home/voy/.buildozer/cache --target=/home/voy/workspace/ketchuporo/.buildozer/applibs pillow[0m
[0m[1;31m# [0m
[0m[1;31m# Buildozer failed to execute the last command[0m
[0m[1;31m# The error might be hidden in the log above this error[0m
[0m[1;31m# Please read the full log, and search for it before[0m
[0m[1;31m# raising an issue with buildozer itself.[0m
[0m[1;31m# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2[0m
```

in virtualenv Pillow was installed without trouble

How to build this app? ;_;

Answer (score 2):

It looks like python-for-android only has a recipe for PIL right now, you'd need to replace `pillow` with `pil` in your requirements. With what you have now, it has no special compilation recipe and so cannot automatically package pillow for android because of its compiled components.

It probably wouldn't be hard to write a pillow recipe, since it would presumably be very similar to the pil one.

Comment: oh, I understand. Didn't knew the _recipes_. I changed requirement to `PIL`. Apk is built, but still crashes. I'll keep looking. Thank You!

Comment: What exactly did you add? Possibly the requirement must be lowercase.

Comment: yup, I added pil requirement written with lowercase: https://github.com/v0y/ketchuporo/blob/master/buildozer.spec#L36